# How to search a specific keyword in all the aura components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, search

Please let me know how do I make a search with a specific keyword in all the existing aura components and it should give me a result of all the aura components having the search term. **I tried SOSL search, but it does not return aura components in result.**

For example, I want to search "ChildComp" in Salesforce, which should return all the components having this search term (in this case it should return ParentComp.cmp, described as below).

```
<aura:component>
        <aura:handler name="componentEventFired" event="c:CustomEvent" action="{!c.handleEvent}"></aura:handler> <!-- Handler for custom event -->
        <aura:attribute name="ParentAttribute" type="String" default=""></aura:attribute> <!-- Attribute of parent component -->
        The ValueOf Attribute is {!v.ParentAttribute}
        <hr />
        <c:ChildComp />
</aura:component>
```

**Note:** I am working on client machine and **I do not have VS Code installed**. Plus it's not possible to have Salesforce DX in my system.

Comment: Is your actual objective to perform a full text search, or to find component dependencies, or something else? Unfortunately it seems you've taken most of the suitable tools off the table.

Comment: @DavidReed Yes, you are right !

Comment: if you have no chance of installing anything nor having chrome extensions... my suggestion would be to export the metadata of the components using workbench, unzip it and use the command `findstr` or any other tool to search in all files

Comment: Install vscode and sfdx and fetch all metadata in vscode using sfdx and search locally in app folder.

Comment: SOSL search gives you the result of record available in sObject.

Comment: @SergioAlcocer: Thank a lot! That seems to be a very good option in this scenario. Can you please write this in the answer section?

Comment: @TilakRaj: It is not possible to install VS Code in client machine. I have already mentioned it as a Note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no chance of installing anything nor having chrome extensions, but you are able to unzip, I would suggest trying workbench (if they haven't blocked it).

Fetch the Aura components with your package.xml (example below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

After some time it will allow you to download the `retrieve_xyz.zip`. Just unzip it and search for its contents using any tool available.

- Portable apps (such as notepad ++)
- Command Line `findstr` (windows) / `find | grep` (unix)
- OS tools (for example try things like `content:yourcomponent`; I cannot test this one as I don't have a windows machine at hand)